# How do I configure OpenSwan to allow pure IPsec (not L2TP) connections from an iPhone?

Tags: linux, vpn, ipsec, apple-ios, openswan

Similar to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/212382/how-to-set-up-strongswan-or-openswan-for-pure-ipsec-with-iphone-client), I want to configure an IPsec server on Linux which will accept connections from the iPhone. However, unlike the other question, I want to be able to test with pre-shared keys before making the jump to certificates.

According to [this page](http://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/IOS_(Apple)), this can't work with StrongSwan because it doesn't support aggressive mode (and will never support it, according to the [FAQ](http://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/FAQ)). So this question is limited in scope to OpenSwan.

I have not been able to find an OpenSwan or StrongSwan configuration that works with pre-shared key authentication on the iPhone client.

Note that I do NOT want to use L2TP.

Can anyone provide an `ipsec.conf` configuration that is known to be working?

Comment: This question, as written, is probably obsolete now. StrongSwan offers a `WeakSwan` option now which should allow this configuration. I haven't tested yet.