# strongswan: entirely virtual subnet

Tags: ipsec, strongswan, vpn

I recently set up a strongswan IPSec VPN to access some non-public services of my home server from my android smartphone. I am using OpenVPN on some other devices for the same task, but chose strongswan for the phone, as IKEv2 is supposed (correct me if I am wrong) to be very resource friendly on mobile devices.

The current (openvpn) setup consists of one server (virtual ip: 10.0.0.2) and multiple clients (all in the 10.0.0.0/24 subnet). The routes on all parties are set up to route only packets through the vpn, that are dedicated to this subnet. (I **don't** want to access the local subnet of my server from a client and I also **don't** want to route all the traffic of my clients through the server)

Now I kind of managed to get things going with strongswan (server: 5.0.4, client: official strongswan android app 1.3.0), but I am not completely there yet. First of all, the server configuration:

```
config setup

conn %default
  keyexchange=ikev2

conn android
  left=%any
  leftauth=pubkey
  leftcert=serverCert.pem
  leftid=vpn.mydomain.com
  leftsourceip=10.10.10.128
  leftfirewall=yes
  right=%any
  rightsourceip=10.10.10.0/24
  rightauth=pubkey
  rightcert=clientCert_mymobilephone.pem
  rightauth2=eap-mschapv2
  auto=start
```

This assigns the IP 10.10.10.1 to my phone, but no IP to the server on any if its interfaces, which would be what I want. I can still access my server via the VPN by using its local IP (192.168.1.2), which is not really what I intended ;)

I would like to migrate all clients (mostly notebooks) from OpenVPN to strongswan, but the issue above prevents me from making the switch. I tried numerous different strongswan configurations, but none could match my OpenVPN config. Is that even possible, if so how?

Comment: This question, although interesting, appears to be off-topic because it is about a home setting, please take a look [here](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Point taken. I didn't know about that policy. However serverfault is full of obvious home settings (e.g. [here](http://serverfault.com/q/212382/110270) or [here](http://serverfault.com/q/257970/110270)) and I imagine that my question is also relevant for some enterprise applications. Additionally, all the servers that I manage for a living are in the OpenVPN network, so ... ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that opposed to OpenVPN, StrongSWAN is not intended to be used in this fashion - it does not create virtual interfaces and does not assign virtual IP addresses to both sides of the tunnel. What you definitely *could* do is adding the address 10.0.0.2 to one of your interfaces  on the server side

```
ip addr add 10.0.0.2/32 dev eth0
```

and adding the appropriate "leftsubnet" directive to your config so it would be part of the IPSEC Phase 2 exchange. Needless to say you would need to be using ESP with tunneling in this case.

Comment: I was under the impression, that I am already using ESP with tunneling. Is that not the case?

Comment: Assigning the IP adress and adding the leftsubnet works, thanks! Could you elaborate what you mean by ESP with tunneling?

Comment: @FabianHenze yes, you do - StrongSwan uses the tunnel mode by default. I just added the remark to make the point that transport mode would not work out with this kind of configuration.

Comment: "it does not create virtual interfaces and does not assign virtual IP addresses to both sides of the tunnel." --> How about this: https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/VirtualIp?

Comment: @quanta it still would not support adding a virtual IP to the server - which is what the OP wanted. As for the clients, it would work, but you  would not get separate interfaces unless you are using something like the [libipsec plugin](https://wiki.strongswan.org/projects/strongswan/wiki/Kernel-libipsec)